# report migration from SQL server to Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I have a report in SQL server and I am migrating this to Oracle.

1. The approach I used in SQL server is load sum(sales) , person for given month into temporary tables (hash tables) and use this table to join with other transaction tables show the details, but when it comes to oracle I am not sure if I can use the same method here, because hash tables (temporary tables in SQL server) are specific to session and might not create any problem with output, please advise if there is anything in oracle which is analogous to that.
2. I came to know there are global temp tables in oracle, do they work in the manner I mentinoed above, also
3. If a user has no create/drop table privileges can they still use gloabal temp tables?

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to show some code or atleast some pseudo-code of how your process runs for anyone to help you. Having said that...

1. One thing that is different in oracle compared to temporary tables in other databases is that you do not create them each time you need them. You create them once and the data in the table is present either until you commit/rollback (transaction based) or until you end your session (session-based global temporary tables). Also, The data in a temporary table is visible only to the session that inserts the data into the table..
2. If you are generating the output files once and you don't need that data later, then Global temporary tables would probably fit in cleanly, with some minor changes.
3. Since you do not create the temporary tables each time you use them, you don't need the create/drop privilege. All you'd need is the insert/read privilege. Just read will not help because you cannot read another session's data anyways, so there is no use for it.